# Jasper Map component is not shown in report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Have problem with Jasper report. All experiments with Google+Jasper were not useful for me.
Please show me the way.

I have:

1. Jasper report: Page header and Details sections
2. 2 String fields ${geo.latitude} and ${geo.latitude}
3. I render the fields as text fields and I have in report good looking double coordinates values.

Experience 1:

I place Map component in the Header section.
Do absolutelly nothing more... Compile and run my application. Render PDF report and see no map. I mean ABSOLUTELLY no rendered map... Empty place.

Experience 2:

I place Map component in the Header section.
Define:

```
Lat. expr = new Float($F{geo.latitude})
Lon. expr = new Float($F{geo.longitude})
```

and get the same result... Nothing is rendered on the place of the map.

Experience 3:

Now I play with markers and so...
Result is the same.

What should I do to get the map in my PDF report?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work as i did not have any GEO data to work with as fields i used a Input parameter instead but it work in the page header, title, column header.  this may also help [Experimenting with Japsersoft 5.0.1 product using Markers in Google Map](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/experimenting-japsersoft-501-product-using-markers-google-map)

```
<pageHeader>
    <band height="116" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement uuid="d16ce41f-66bd-4fdb-9d6c-31e661b0f16f" key="" x="0" y="0" width="134" height="116"/>
            <mp:map xmlns:mp="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <mp:latitudeExpression><![CDATA[$P{geo.latitude}]]></mp:latitudeExpression>
                <mp:longitudeExpression><![CDATA[$P{geo.longitude}]]></mp:longitudeExpression>
                <mp:zoomExpression><![CDATA[3]]></mp:zoomExpression>
                <mp:markerData>
                    <mp:item>
                        <mp:itemProperty name="id" value="CHANGE_ME"/>
                        <mp:itemProperty name="latitude" value="20"/>
                        <mp:itemProperty name="longitude" value="-10.2"/>
                    </mp:item>
                </mp:markerData>
            </mp:map>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
```

Comment: Thanks I found the solution. Problem was I used reports version 4.0. It does not contain map information. So when I saved the report all map info was cleared from XML. So I updated iReport+Jasper jar+Jasper version in report. Everything works fine now. Thanks.